# systemctl stop not stopping all process in redhat

Tags: linux, rhel, java, systemctl

I am starting a service using systemctl ,but I am facing issue to stop the service in redhat system.

the service file I am creating :

```
[Unit]
Description=/home/agenttest
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/agenttest/service/test.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

in test.sh I am using below command :

```
sudo /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agenttest/service/agent.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/test.properties,/home/agenttest/service/test.properties --server.port=8081
```

the service successfully started :

[image]

But when I stop the service using `systemctl stop <service_name>` command ,all processes are not getting stopped.

I stop the services using below command:

```
sudo systemctl stop ConnectOnceAgent_8081_PROD_SYSTEMCTL

sudo systemctl disable ConnectOnceAgent_8081_PROD_SYSTEMCTL
```

But all the process is running though the services are showing stopped:

```
4     0 10166 10129  20   0 3466036 296488 -    Sl   ?          3:58 /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agenttest/service/agent.jar -
4     0 10167 10135  20   0 3463436 517428 -    Sl   ?          2:00 /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agenttest/service/agent.jar -
4     0 10168 10140  20   0 3460760 514544 -    Sl   ?          2:01 /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agenttest/service/agent.jar -
4     0 10169 10142  20   0 3460760 531220 -    Sl   ?          2:03 /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agenttest/service/agent.jar -
4     0 10170 10141  20   0 3460684 515260 -    Sl   ?          2:02 /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agentt
```

when I am running `ps -ef | grep -i 8081`,it is showing below logs:

```
root     10140     1  0 Sep18 ?        00:00:00 sudo /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agenttest/service/agent.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/executorService.properties,/home/agenttest/service/ConnectOnceAgent_8081_PROD.properties --server.port=8081
root     10168 10140  0 Sep18 ?        00:02:01 /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agenttest/service/agent.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/executorService.properties,/home/agenttest/service/ConnectOnceAgent_8081_PROD.properties --server.port=8081
ec2-user 17230 17186  0 10:44 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i 8081
```

I am seeing the issue in redhat only.For other Linux system it is working fine.

but all the process still running though the services are showing stopped:

Also I have changed the `KillMode=mixed` to other properties like control-group, process, mixed not noting work properly.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you manually run the stop code, does it work?

Comment: BTW, the `sudo` line in the first block should not be in the service file, right? Is it a cut-and-paste error perhaps?

Comment: @ScottieH: No it showing same issue if I stop it manually.Process are not getting killed.

Comment: @NickD:yes it is cut and paste error ,edited

Comment: Are all the processe that are created by the service file still there after you stop the service? Or only some of them? Can you show a `ps awlx` listing of the (relevant) processes? Not sure what that will show but more info is better: please edit the question and add any information that might help us understand what is going on.

Comment: @NickD. Thanks for validating.I have updated more info .Please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: Please cut and paste output into text blocks in your question: don't use images unless it's really unavoidable. First, images can go away without warning; second, for me and my old, tired eyes, they are unreadable.

Comment: Very hard to read the images. Text block is better if possible. What command are you using to stop the processes?

Comment: Attached text ,in my information

Comment: Please read https://jdebp.eu/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/tomcat.html

Comment: Is that one line the total contents of your test.sh script?  If not, please paste total contents of that script.  And see the link I gave above for advice on properly setting up a java service in systemd.

Comment: yes that is the only line in test.sh.

sudo /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agenttest/service/agent.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/test.properties,/home/agenttest/service/test.properties --server.port=8081

we are using this command to start the process,test.sh is stored in /home/agenttest/service/ folder in my local system

Answer (score 0):

systemctl is stopping the main process 3714. However subprocess created by `/home/agenttest/service/test.sh` is left alive.

Consider changing following

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/agenttest/service/test.sh
```

to following

```
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/bin/java -jar /home/agenttest/service/agent.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/test.properties,/home/agenttest/service/test.properties --server.port=8081
```